# Intent putExtra inside ViewHolder of RecyclerView (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I'm creating a RecyclerViewAdapter that has the following **onBind** and **ViewHolder** inerrclass:

```
class PreviewMuseoRecyclerViewAdapter(private val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<PreviewMuseoRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

  override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val item = museus[position]
    holder.nom.text = item.nom
    holder.direccio.text = item.direccio}

inner class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    val nom: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.museu_nom)
    val direccio: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.museu_direccio)
        view.setOnClickListener{
            Log.i("hola","Funciona2")
            context?.startActivity(Intent(context, Mood::class.java))
        }
    }
}
```

I was able to start the new activity with the context provided (inside **ViewHolder**), but since that was the only place I could make the onClickListener work (inside **onBind** it doesn't), I don't have the value I need to provide to **putExtra**. **I need to pass an attribute of an item, inside **onBindViewholder**** (this wouldn't be a problem if startActivity() worked there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the item when clicking on a view holder, use the [`getAdapterPosition()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder?hl=en#getAdapterPosition()) method:

```
view.setOnClickListener {
    val adapterPosition = adapterPosition
    if (adapterPosition == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
        return@setOnClickListener
    }

    Log.i("hola","Funciona2")
    val item = museus[adapterPosition];
    // Pass item to intent and start activity
}
```

It is important to check for `RecyclerView.NO_POSITION` because it can happen that an item which has "no position" is clicked. This can happen when an item is clicked while being removed, during an animation.

Note: In later versions of `androidx.recyclerview`, `getAdapterPosition()` was deprecated in favor of `getBindingAdapterPosition()`. Use that if you are on the latest version.